# How to install Oracle 12C on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, oracle, makefile

I tried an unsuccessful installation of Oracle 12C on Ubuntu 16.04.1 64 bits several times.
Typically, I get the error:

> Error in invoking target 'all_no_rcl' of makefile
> '.../rdbms/ins_rdbms.mk'.
> See '....log' for details.

[image]

Comment: I am busy using these instructions and progressing further than I originally did on the same site but on a different page: http://tutorialforlinux.com/2016/11/06/how-to-install-oracle-12c-database-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-lts-64bit-easy-guide-users-directories-set-up/

Answer (score 0):

go to root and do

```
xhost +
```

in the same terminal window,

```
su - oracle
./runInstaller
```

Comment: A bit more flesh would help us understand your answer.